# Creating a div and inserting HTML

Tags: javascript, append, innerhtml, createelement

I'm trying to create this in Javascript so that I can insert it into the document:

```
    <div class="listing-small-badge award-badge" style=" vertical-align: top; position: relative; top: -250px; z-index: 2;"><i class="fa fa-tag award" style="background-color: #990000;"></i>Highest Rated</div>
```

And I've tried everything I can think of, but once I create the 'i' element, I can't seem to properly append it to the div element.

For example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.cssText += 'vertical-align:top; position: relative; top:-250px; z-index:2;';
    div.classList.add("listing-small-badge");
    div.classList.add("award-badge");
    div.innerHTML = "Highest Rated"; //this works on its own, but disappears if/when I try to append the 'i' element/HTML tag
    var i = document.createElement("i");
    i.classList.add("fa");
    i.classList.add("fa-tag");
    i.classList.add("award");
    //i.style.cssText("background-color: #990000;"); //doesn't like this for some reason TBD
    //console.log(i); //prints out just fine
    //div.innerHTML += i; //results in an empty div
    //div.innerHTML += '<i class="test">x</i>'; //results in an empty div
    //div.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<i class='test'></i>"); //results in "The element has no parent."
    console.log(div);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can dynamically add html using js

//js file

```
function createElements() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");

  div.classList.add("listing-small-badge");
  div.classList.add("award-badge");
  div.innerHTML = "Highest Rated";
  div.innerText='Dusting';
  var i = document.createElement("i");
  i.classList.add("fa");
  i.classList.add("fa-tag");
  i.classList.add("award");
  i.href = 'google.com';
  i.innerText = 'google';
  div.appendChild(i);
  const body = document.querySelector('body');

  body.appendChild(div);


    window.onload = (e)=>{

      createElements();

    }
    
    }
```

//html

```
<body>
  
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I don't want to have to click a button to insert the code, but that aside, I put the core part of your function in the script, and it resulted in an empty div (though with the proper classes). I'm beginning to think that the issue is with the 'Scripts and Styles' plugin that I'm using to put the script on the (WordPress) page.

Comment: when do you want to add this div with a tag on the page?

Comment: On pageload, I suppose. I was FINALLY able to get it working with jQuery, though I'm baffled as to why it would be necessary. Or maybe it's the fact that it's in a function?

Anyway, thank you kindly for your time and contribution.

Comment: you could simply use window.onload  event to call the mentioned function.
And yes jQuery isn't needed.

Comment: But you're overlooking the fact that your code was still resulting in an empty div for some reason yet TBD, regardless of when it runs.

Comment: shared code, results in <div class="listing-small-badge award-badge">Dusting<i class="fa fa-tag award">google</i></div> as output not an empty div try to inspect the html to be sure.
https://jsfiddle.net/bipingosain/y0b67wh9/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm at a loss as to why jQuery would be necessary, but here's what worked:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var htmlData = '<div class="listing-small-badge award-badge" style="vertical-align: top; position: relative; top: -250px; z-index: 2;"><i 
        class="fa fa-tag award" style="background-color: #990000;"></i>Highest Rated</div>';
        $('body p').append(htmlData);
    });
```